# socket.io in django template - node.js not service socket.io.js

Tags: javascript, django, node.js, express, socket.io

i have Django app which need to use real time push to client.
i want to use node.js and socket.io (which i understood is the easiest platform to do it today..).
to implement it i put the socket.io framework code on the template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% if error %}
  <div id="error">
        <h3>{{ error }}</h3>
  </div>
{% endif %}
<div id="reply">

<script src="http://localhost:8889/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8889');

        socket.on('connect', function(){
                socket.emit('addOrder', 99, {{ reply_id }});
        });

</script>
Thank you for your reply
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my node.js runs on 8889 as you can see.. so i need to call "script src" to import it from localhost:8889/socket.io/socket.io.js (the Django server and the node.js server is the same server. this is why i am using localhost).

the issue is that when i calling to this template (render it from view), and using F12 on chrome, i see "CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.".
i tried to check here what is means but i only saw talks about AdBlocks, so i uninstalled it, but i still getting this error...

after more investigation i saw that even on apache (native HTML files) i cannot get the js file (same error).

it looks like the reason is i have to use node.js http server (express) to serve this file, and cannot call it from any other web server.

Does anyone have any idea what can be the reason or how to fix it?

**Node.js Server code:**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(8889));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.get('/menu.css', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/menu.css');
});
var branches = {};
ojson = {"count":1,"orders":[{"id":100,"state":"ok"}]};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('connectBranch', function(branchID) {
                //save ID info on the socket
                socket.branchID = branchID
                // save the socket of the branch by ID
                branches[branchID]=socket;
                // ask the client to run getAll function with orders JSON
                branches[branchID].emit('getAll', ojson);
        });

        // clear - for test
        socket.on('clearOrders', function(branchID) {
                branches[branchID].emit('clearOrders');
        });

        // when the client emits 'addOrder', this listens and executes
        socket.on('addOrder', function(branchID, orderID){
                console.log(branches);
                branches[branchID].emit('addOrder', orderID);
        });

        // when the user disconnects.. perform this
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                // remove the branch from global branches list
                delete branches[socket.branchID];
        });
});
```

Comment: can you please provide code for your serverside `node.js` script

Comment: what response do you get when you try to access `http://localhost:8889/socket.io/socket.io.js` from your browser?

Comment: the server sit on AWS (amazon), so localhost from my browser will not work. http://SERVER_IP:8889:/socket.io/socket.io.js gives me the javascript 
(Start with "/*! Socket.IO.js build:0.9.16, development. Copyright(c) 2011 LearnBoost <dev@learnboost.com> MIT Licensed */").
from the server itself, using "curl http://localhost:8889/socket.io/socket.io.js" i get the same javascript page. so all is good beside Django template :).. Thanks!

Comment: why does your template refers to localhost then? change it to `<script src="http://SERVER_IP:8889/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: i will try to change it now. but i need the internal IP of the machine, not the external, right? the machine is Amazon EC2 machine with elastic IP attached.. i will give it a try now

Comment: you need the external IP address, because your client (browser) accessing it from outside AWS environment, in other words you need to specify same full URL as when you did when I asked you to access it from your browser.

Comment: magician... it works! how can i mark it as an answer here? THANKS!!!

Comment: because it is `localhost` in relation to the client - which is always same IP address `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unless you are running this on a `localhost`

```
<script src="http://localhost:8889/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

needs to be changed to

```
<script src="http://SERVER_IP:8889/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

better yet, if your frontent HTTP server is NGINX or similar, you can proxy calls to `socket.io.js` to port 8889, and then change your page to

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

this way you dont have to specify IP, it will be the same as the one where original HTML page came from

Comment: BTW - i am running the node.js and Django on the same hosts.. i still dont understand why localhost not good here...

Comment: because it is `localhost` in relation to the client - which is always same IP address `127.0.0.1`

Comment: ohhhh.. so stupid.. funny how cant you see things when you deep into it.. :) Thanks!